# Drawing custom Editor controls in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Sometimes a Unity project has data that demands more than ordinary inspector fields and we want to create more sophisticated tools to edit the data. For example, here's a blog post about creating a node editor: [Creating a Node Based Editor in Unity](https://gram.gs/gramlog/creating-node-based-editor-unity/)

It's useful to be able to create node editors, but that project draws nothing but boxes and  lines and curves using the tools in GUI and Handles, which is fine for what it is, but what if we need to draw something not supplied by Handles?

For example, if we want to draw an elaborate mesh to represent some data that we want to be able to edit, it seems not ideal to render each individual polygon of the mesh using Handles.DrawAAConvexPolygon(...). Shouldn't we instead have a way to more directly send the mesh to be rendered? Or is DrawAAConvexPolygon exactly what we should be doing?

Is the GL class the appropriate approach when wanting to draw arbitrary meshes in an editor control? It is certainly capable of drawing, but is it bad practice? In particular, the GL.Viewport(Rect) method seems to work very strangely within a GUI. One cannot simply give it a GUI Rect and thereby have a viewport in the same place we'd have a GUI control if we gave it that same Rect. We need to calculate the Rect that will put the viewport in the appropriate place, and even then we have to determine the coordinate system within the viewport. Based on the documentation for Viewport(Rect) one might expect the viewport to be (0, 0) to (Screen.width, Screen.height), but it does not always work out that way exactly, and it all gives the impression that GL is not designed to be used within Editor GUI. The documentation for GL.Viewport has it used in an OnPostRender method, so is it misguided to try to use GL in other places?

If we should not be using the GL class, then what is the technique for drawing within custom Editor controls?

Comment: What do you want do draw in the Inspector exactly?

Comment: @derHugo: The exact details of the project are far too complicated to include and we wouldn't want to distract from the point of the question, but I've added to the question to give more of a sense of what someone might want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna look at Unity Graph view if you want to make a Node Based Editor in Unity.
It use UXML and USS with is close to HTML and CSS.
Making it pretty easy to customise as you wanted.

Unity Video on UXML and USS: Customize the Unity Editor with UIElements!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ39btQ0XlE&t=98s

Here are 3 Github you can download and look at.

https://github.com/rygo6/GTLogicGraph
[image]

https://github.com/rygo6/GraphViewExample

This one is made by me.

https://github.com/KasperGameDev/Dialogue-Editor-Tutorial/tree/Dialogue-Prototype-Bonus
[image]